# How to move to the slide when showing the screen

Tags: ios, swift, move

Now my screen is shown moving from bottom to top as Screen move. But I want to be seen moving from left to right. What can I do?

**Current Move Sidebar Screen**

```swift
    func openSidebarScreen(){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let side = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideMenuWebViewController") as! SideMenuWebViewController
        side.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        side.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        side.delegate = self
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "open", sender: qrcodeScan)
    }
```

### The direction I want the sidebar to open.

[image]

Comment: You would like to move from one screen to another screen or perform something like side menu?

Comment: @MaulikPandya Yes, I would like to move from left to right when I want moving between two UIViewController

Comment: @hongdevelop, Why won't you try to use `UIView.animate` and change frame.

Comment: @dahiya_boy  I don't have much knowledge of Swift, so please explain it in detail.

Comment: It seems you are not using UINavigationController properly. moving to another storyboard need UINavigationController as a bridge

Comment: @dahiya_boy And my side menu must takes up the whole screen. So I made two web view controllers on the main story board. Main webview controller, side menu webview controller

Comment: @MaulikPandya It looks like a good way. How is this possible?

Comment: @hongdevelop, Check this -> [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622515-animate) and many more func are available at the end on page. If you search on google **'UIView.animate in swift'** then you got lots of tutorials and link which explains how to use. For now you can check [raywenderlich-basic-uiview-animation](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5255-basic-uiview-animation-tutorial-getting-started), Your question is too broad now, it's hard to explain.

Comment: @dahiya_boy Well... as you can see from my question, I don't show UIView. I use the UIViewController. I go to one new controller page.

Comment: @MaulikPandya Could you look at my edited question?

Comment: @dahiya_boy I will try the NavigationController. Could you look at the edited question of where it went wrong?

Comment: @hongdevelop Can you upload your sample project on github and share link to us. Make sure it will be in only swift.

Comment: @dahiya_boy  I was Fixed a problem that was not moved, but moved from right to left. How can I move to the left?

Comment: @hongdevelop Please update how you moved it from left to right. Because both way are same. I had github repo, you can take ref from [there](https://github.com/thedahiyaboy/TDSIdeMenuSamples). Hope it helps

Comment: @dahiya_boy I wrote the wrong comment. Please look at my revised question. There's an updated code. And this code moves from right to left. But I want to move from left to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, I applied basic animation using the navigation controller.

> The default direction moves from right to left.

[image]

2. Second, I modified the navigation controller's direction
   (RightToLeft)

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
        navigationController?.navigationBar.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    }
```

3. Thirdly, the screen is moved through navigation.

```swift
    func openSidebarScreen(){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let side = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideMenuWebViewController") as! SideMenuWebViewController
        side.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        side.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        side.delegate = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(side, animated: true)
    }
```